# Location of the key to the chest in the secret area outside the halls of the dead

Tags: legend-of-grimrock-2

In the halls of the dead, you can open a secret area and end up on a beach. There is a chest there but it is locked.

Is the key in that area, or somewhere later? Because I beat the first boss and I still can't find it anywhere in the area. I dug up the entire beach and found nothing.

Answer (score 3):

There are no keys for chests in Grimrock 2. But you might have noticed you have (or should have) acquired several lockpicks. Now would be the time to use them.